# AssertionError when cloning Anaconda base environment

Tags: windows, python-3.x, anaconda

I'm trying to create a clone of my base anaconda environment for a specific application. I want to use the clone as the base off of which to install application-specific packages. I used the following command to start the clone:

```
C:\Users\Liam>conda create -n retrievals --clone base
```

It made it a long way through the cloning process, and had just reach 100% on cloning anaconda-5.2.0, when it threw the assertion error below:

```
# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Liam\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 819, in __call__
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Liam\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 78, in _main
    exit_code = do_call(args, p)
  File "C:\Users\Liam\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\conda_argparse.py", line 77, in do_call
    exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
  File "C:\Users\Liam\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_create.py", line 11, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'create')
  File "C:\Users\Liam\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 211, in install
    clone(args.clone, prefix, json=context.json, quiet=context.quiet, index_args=index_args)
  File "C:\Users\Liam\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\install.py", line 72, in clone
    index_args=index_args)
  File "C:\Users\Liam\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\misc.py", line 277, in clone_env
    force_extract=False, index_args=index_args)
  File "C:\Users\Liam\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\misc.py", line 78, in explicit
    assert not any(spec_pcrec[1] is None for spec_pcrec in specs_pcrecs)
AssertionError
```

`$ C:\Users\Liam\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda create -n retrievals --clone base`

Can anybody explain why this is happening and what I could try to fix it?

P.S. I'm doing this on Windows 10 if that helps at all.

Comment: I verified on another computer that cloning the base environment with an older version of Anaconda did work. I was then able to duplicate this error on that computer by uninstalling the older version, installing the latest version of Anaconda and attempting to clone the base environment. The exact same error message was raised.

This is now an issue on conda github from more than one user, and seems to be related to a very similar issue raised in 2016 on conda github.

Answer (score 0):

I found workaround for it. You can just copy environment with base name.

```
cp -r /opt/conda/envs/base_env /opt/conda/envs/new_env
```

After that you can activate or update environment.

```
conda activate new_env

conda env update --name new_env --file environment.yaml --prune
```